# The Program (web or program) that can tutorial and test user about how to use the application

Tags: windows, testing, web-applications

I want to know the program name that can help me to teach the user and can test the user.

For example, I develop web application and I want to train user how to use this web application (using VDO). After training, I want to test the user that user know about my web. (EX. Please go to ABC page -> user try to use user interface to go to ABC page can or can't)

I want the program that can help me to do like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Camstudio software to record video tutorial then create a simple survey to know if the user know about your website.

to download Camstudio : [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/)